# Calling powershell script from a lambda function

Tags: python, powershell, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

I am writing a lambda function which is triggered by a cloud watch event when a EC2 instance gets terminated. So my function extracts the instance-id from the Json message. Now I need to pass this instance id to a powershell function so that my active directory objects gets deleted. Can someone help me how to call a powershell script within a lambda function and how to pass the parameters.

Comment: share the piece of code.

Comment: How would you normally call a PowerShell script that runs on a Windows machine, if you're not on that machine? What have you tried so far? For tips on how to ask a good question, see: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)